# Which of the following cannot be the length of triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a question regarding triangles which is puzzling me:

> > In triangle PQR , PR=7  and PQ=4.5 . Which of the following cannot represent the length of
> >     QR ? a)2.0 , b)3 , c)3.5 , d)4.5 , e)5.0

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What do you know about the sum of the sides of a triangle with respect to the remaining side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the two smaller sides must be greater than the last side.
So 2 can't be the length of QR : 2+4.5=6.5<7

Comment: Not surprisingly, this restriction is called the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.. I'll definitely keep this in mind

Answer (score 1):

Any set of three lengths can represent the sides of a triangle provided the largest is smaller than the other two combined.

Therefore, the answer is (a) 2.0.  The length PR of 7 is too long to support sides of 4.5 and 2.0.